# I am implementing file drag and drop feature

Tags: javascript, html

I have one button onClick of which one dialog box opens for either browse and select file or drag and drop file on the dialog box area.Currently i have the whole window as the drop area.How can i make the modal area as drop area.

```
if (window.File && window.FileList) {
  var dropArea = document.body; //This area i need to change..
  dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", dragHandler);
  dropArea.addEventListener("drop", filesDroped);
}
```

Comment: `var dropArea = document.getElementById('modalArea')`?

Comment: Sorry @FrankerZ, i think this approach wont work for me. My modal id is being created dynamically which changes every time i open the modal box. Is there any way to select the active part of the window. I am assuming that on opening any dialog other part of window becomes passive and only the dialog area is active. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: You'd have to initialize the drop when the modal is being created. Create a `modalDrop()` function, and call that when the modal is created. Attach the drop area after the modal is created.

Comment: Use Dropzone http://www.dropzonejs.com/

This will help you a lot !

Comment: Thank you FrankerZ and Ankit vadariya. I will try out your suggestions and will update if i am able to do it.

Comment: I hope the following codes right here may help you http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Drag-Drop-File-Upload-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-dropzone.html. The following codes are available right here https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/#download. I also recommend to visit https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html, https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-file-uploads/. I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This method of uploading image is via ajax,php and javascript. This method is contains two files **index.html** and **upload.php**. In addition, **you need to create a folder where you need to upload your image**, for me I create an image folder. This folder path will be included to upload.php. I hope the this help you a little bit.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
        <div id="drop-container" class="drop-container">
            <h3 class="drop-label">DRAG AND DROP IMAGE HERE</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#drop-container").on('dragenter', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css('background', '#fff');
    });

    $("#drop-container").on('dragover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#drop-container").on('drop', function(e) {
        $(this).css('background', '#fff');
        e.preventDefault();
        var image = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        createFormData(image);
    });
});

function createFormData(image) {
    var formImage = new FormData();
    formImage.append('userImage', image[0]);
    uploadFormData(formImage);
}

function uploadFormData(formData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#drop-container').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 995px;
}

.drop-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 220px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.drop-label {
    margin-top: 120px;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.drop-container img {
    max-width: 200px;
}
</style>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
if(is_array($_FILES)) 
{
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
  $sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];

  //$query=" " //Query to insert to database here.

  if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>">
   <?php
   exit();
  }
 }
}
?>
```